# mysql - has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Bootstrap system that hosted on `Hostinger` web host.

The program that I sign to is premium account.

today we tried to use 20 users in parallel, and suddenly, all of the user got error message:

> User 'u526475971_alber' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 3)

I don't have a lot of privilege, and I don't know if I can change max_user_connections.

What can I do?

Does close con will help?

Comment: Are you closing all of your connections? An open connection will stay open until it times out, and is a security flaw in itself. Make sure you're using **$mysql->close();** once you're done with a conneciton.

Comment: Does a multiple connection from the same user and same browser counts as one or mutiple?

Comment: I'd have thought so. Anyway, if you ever browser user in the end uses the same MySQL account to log in to the DB (which is the way most web apps will be written, you wouldn't normally create a new MySQL user for each human, esp if they are anonymous users), even if you have 20 human users you only have one MySQL user, and max_user_connections applies to each MySQL user. 3 sounds like a low number especially if you really do have a premium account - are you sure this is correct and your premium account has been set up correctly? I'd contact the hosting support.

Comment: But yes make sure you also close the connections properly in your code, especially if any kind of error occurs in the code. If you can, maybe try and use a singleton pattern in your code so that you only open and close the connection once per HTTP request.

Comment: The problem is that I can create only one user per DB.. So I guess Singleton will be the solution. There is option that php will close automatically in every end of php script?

Comment: no, you have to code it AFAIK. PHP doesn't know what DB code you are using automagically. So if you handle exceptions anywhere that causes the script to end or normal flow diverted, make sure you close it then too as well as in the normal flow. Even if you use a singleton, that will reduce the risk of a single HTTP request opening multiple connections, but if there are multiple simultaneous HTTP requests (from the same or different browsers) you can still go over the 3 connection limit very quickly.

Comment: If this is a hard limit for your hosting account then it's not very "premium" - I'd still query it with the hosting company.

Comment: yeah, I already asked about it. The problem is that there is no phone to call so I'll have to wait every message to answer.. I guess I'll look for other host.. for conclusion - mysqli_close($con) supposed to solve it?

Comment: well that closes an individual connection, yes. So it might help, if you weren't doing that already. But it's likely that if you stick 20 users using it simultaneously you could run into the same problem. Add the close statement everywhere it's needed, and test again, and see what happens.

Comment: I tried to put on the footer `mysqli_close` and on every sql page but the keep crushing..

Answer (score 0):

I have just went to phpmyadmin and without selecting any db, i just run this code and my problem solve, as it update max_user_connections for all the db and users.

for detail, info you can visit this link:(https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47131/how-to-get-rid-of-maximum-user-connections-error)

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET max_user_connections = 0
```